# Errno 2: No such file or directory on a random generator

Tags: python

I am using a library in order to add a bot to a program, but I'm unsure about one part in the framework. I don't know why the following code doesn't work:

```
@bot.command()
async def meme():
    path = r"C:\Users\Diego\Dropbox\PycharmProjects\XDBot\freshmemes"
    memeToPost = random.choice([
                             x for x in os.listdir(path)
                             if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
                             ])
    await bot.upload(path+memeToPost)
```

(ignore the @bot.command(), async def meme, and await bot.upload, since it's part of the bot framework I'm using)

Whenever I try to run it, I get [this](http://pastebin.com/ywgf5T14):

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: You can add the code and output directly to your question instead of linking to pastebins.

Comment: Based on the error message in that pastebin, it looks like you tried to upload a file that didn't exist on your system. Have you gone to that directory on your filesystem and looked to see if the file is really there?

Answer (score 0):

Last line, you need to `upload(path + '/' + memeToPost)`

Your code:

```
def meme():
    path = r"C:\Users\Diego\Dropbox\PycharmProjects\XDBot\freshmemes"
    memeToPost = random.choice([
                             x for x in os.listdir(path)
                             if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
                             ])
    await bot.upload(path+memeToPost)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.path.join(path, memeToPost)` instead `path+memeToPost` because you miss `\` between path and filename

Answer (score 0):

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Diego\\Dropbox\\PycharmProjects\\XDBot\\freshmemesmeme1.jpg'
```

Assuming you want a file called `freshmemesmeme1.jpg` in a folder called `XDBot`, It sounds as though you simply haven't got a file called `freshmemesmeme1.jpg` in the relevant folder. Correcting the path (or moving the image to the XDBot folder) should fix the problem :)

However, you more likely want a path like: `C:\Users\Diego\Dropbox\PycharmProjects\XDBot\freshmemes\meme1.jpg`. In that case, you're missing the trailing backslash in the path you define in Python:

```
path = r"C:\Users\Diego\Dropbox\PycharmProjects\XDBot\freshmemes"
```

Should be:

```
path = r"C:\Users\Diego\Dropbox\PycharmProjects\XDBot\freshmemes\"
```

Hope this helps!